# How will factor levels be ordered with regard to the original values?

Tags: r, numerical, categorical-data

If I create a factor from a vector of numerical values, will the factor categories be ordered automatically by the values that are now considered categories?

i.e. [1,4,7,3,2] -> categories = {1,2,3,4,7}

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer: it depends. R will sort the unique values and assign the categories in that order if you convert a vector using the function `factor()` without calling any extra arguments :

```
> x <- c(3,1,4,5,1,4)
> factor(x)
[1] 3 1 4 5 1 4
Levels: 1 3 4 5
```

It won't however when you use the argument `levels`:

```
> factor(x, levels=unique(x))
[1] 3 1 4 5 1 4
Levels: 3 1 4 5
```

In this case, it takes the order of the levels as the order in which it assigns categories.